# Salesforce extract files within Blob Zip File

Tags: zip, salesforce, blob, unzip, apex

I am developing an application in `Salesforce` Where i get a `zip file` form an external server using `HttpRequest`.

The file i get from the server is `Blob`, but i don't know how to process it to extract the files i want.

Here's the code

```
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

       /* Here i set the HttpRequest Attributes*/

        Http http = new Http();                
        HttpResponse response = http.send(req);

        Blob file = response.getBodyAsBlob();

        /*Now i need to access: file to extract the files i want*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the Zippex library. It's open source and available here: https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

/* Here set the HttpRequest Attributes */

Http http = new Http();                
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

Blob file = response.getBodyAsBlob();

//Instantiate Zippex with zip file Blob
Zippex zip = Zippex(file);

for (String fileName : zip.getFileNames()) {    
    //Extract file
    Blob fileData = zip.getFile(fileName);
    //Process the file here
    ...
}
```

Comment: i read an article about Zippex Library a few weeks ago, and it seems to be the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn't support zip file extraction. You will have to do it at your externally hosted service.

Comment: You could improve your answer by generally suggesting implementations of external services.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions ? I didn't find a solution yet

Comment: You may want to try the Expand Container API from HPE Haven OnDemand... https://dev.havenondemand.com/apis/expandcontainer#overview (Disclosure: I work for Hewlett Packard Enterprise)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution, it's not the best one, because to unzip the file i should use an external service, but i am running out of time, so these are the steps i followed:

**1. Create StaticResource for the zip file (i had to use the `Metadata Salesforce Api`)**

**2. extract the file you want by creating a PageReference object with url: `/resource/NameOfResource/NameOfFile**

**3. delete the StaticResource:** i created it only to extract some files, so i don't need it any more.

Here's a sample code of the first point that i get from  [This link](http://andyinthecloud.com/2012/11/04/handling-office-files-and-zip-files-in-apex-part-1/)

```
private static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService()
    { 
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        return service;     
    }    

MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService(); 
MetadataService.StaticResource staticResource = new MetadataService.StaticResource();
staticResource.fullName = nameOfResource;
staticResource.contentType = 'application/zip';
staticResource.cacheControl = 'public';
staticResource.content = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(zipBlobFile);
List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =  service.createMetadata( new MetadataService.Metadata[] { staticResource });
```

and here's the code for the second point that i get from the same link

```
private static String GetResourceURL(String resourceName){
    // Fetching the resource
    List<StaticResource> resourceList= [SELECT Name, NamespacePrefix, SystemModStamp FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = :resourceName];

    // Checking if the result is returned or not
    if(resourceList.size() == 1){

       // Getting namespace
       String namespace = resourceList[0].NamespacePrefix;
       // Resource URL
       return '/resource/' + resourceList[0].SystemModStamp.getTime() + '/' + (namespace != null && namespace != '' ? namespace + '__' : '') + resourceName; 
    }
    else return '';
}

private Blob  getResourceFile(String url, String fileName) {
    PageReference tmp = new PageReference(url + '/' + fileName);
    Blob contentAsBlob = tmp.getContent();

    return contentAsBlob;
}

String url = GetResourceURL(nameOfResource);
Blob myFile = getResourceFile(url, nameOfFileToExtract);
```

For the tird point it's just one line of code :

```
List<MetadataService.DeleteResult> deleteResults =  service.deleteMetadata('StaticResource', new String[] { resourceName });
```

I hope this answer will be usefull.

**EDIT:**

If you have to create the `StaticResource` and then delete it, don't execute `DML` operations between the create and delete `callouts`, instead of that execute the `DML` operation after or before the `Callout`, unless you want to execute the `callout` in a `@future` method but it didn't work for me.